# Linking post to authenticated user - How do I use current_user in the controller? (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using the Rails "Getting Started" blog post exercise, and trying to integrate with Devise for authentication and authoring of posts.

When creating an Article, the Author should be the currently logged-in user.

I am getting an error when trying to Create an Article.  I know that the error is in my Articles controller, but I can't seem to figure out how to grab the current logged-in Author to kick off the creation of an Article.  I believe I did the relationship properly between an Author and an Article.

Error:  undefined method `articles' for nil:NilClass

Author Model:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

Articles Model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
   length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

Articles Controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[: id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[: id])
  end

  def create
    @author = @current_author
    @article = @author.articles.create(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[: id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[: id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(: article).permit(: title,: text,: author)
  end
end
```

Comment: just use `@author = current_author`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the @ from @current_author. With devise, current_author is a method that returns the user by session[:user_id] not an instance variable.

Also, try doing one of three things....

1. Change

   ```
   @author.articles.create(atricle_params)
   ```

   to

   ```
   @author.articles.new(atricle_params)
   ```
2. Move the assignment of the author to the 'new' method as so...

   ```
   def new
     @article = Article.new
     @article.author = current_user
   end
   ```
3. Add a hidden_field to your form...

   ```
   '<%= f.hidden_field :author_id, current_user.id %>
   ```

   '

Comment: Thank you! The first suggestion of using current_author rather than @current_author worked.

Comment: Glad I could help.